# Using selected packages from JAR Vs importing full JAR File

Tags: java, war, packaging, embedded-jetty

My project needs a small Java based component. The component has to be developed as lightweight, self contained unit with minimum use of any open source framework. Since the component needs to expose some REST services, we are planning to use 'Embedded Jetty' as server.

My manager wants to go one step further and use only those packages of Jetty which are relevant for HTTP/2 Server requirement. He wants to import source code of relevant packages from Jetty's codebase rather than using complete JAR file(s) coming from maven.

I would like to know if there are any advantages to this approach? Does this approach gives any edge during runtime - say memory management and performance - if the size of final WAR is small?

Comment: Since classes are loaded one by one on demand I doubt that there are any benefits in stripping out unused code from a WAR file (beyond filesize). OTOH the maintenance overhead and the risk of stripping out too much could be significant. Either use Jetty as is (supposedly lightweight), or find something even smaller.

Comment: You can use the FULL Jetty on a system with as little as 16MB (yes, MegaBytes) of memory.  You'll be wasting hundreds of man hours attempting to shave off about 1% or 2% in an effort for performance that is ultimately pointless.   Ask yourself what's important: start serving content quickly? or memory/threads/cpu?  (tip: this is what the docker folks have already answered)

Comment: Thanks. "You'll be wasting hundreds of man hours attempting to shave off about 1% or 2% in an effort for performance that is ultimately pointless" <-- Totally makes sense. (+1)

Comment: Also note, Jetty is already modular, its not 1 jar, its about 30 (last time I counted),  Pick and choose what you want, don't use it all if you don't need to.